# How to subtract two different size image and grayscale image in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have 3 Images, I try to subtract First and Second image that have same size dimensions and got the result. next, I try to subtract First and Third image, First Image have dimensions(2000x1000) and Third Image have dimensions(1200x1057) and i got an error.

```
//! [window]
namedWindow("min", WINDOW_NORMAL);
resizeWindow("min", 1000, 500);
namedWindow("plus", WINDOW_NORMAL); 
resizeWindow("plus", 1000, 500); 
namedWindow("adf", WINDOW_NORMAL); 
resizeWindow("adf", 1000, 500);

Mat min,plus,adf;

subtract(im, im2, min);  //error 
add(im, im2, plus);
absdiff(im, im2, adf);

imshow("min", min); 
imshow("plus", plus);
imshow("adf", adf);
```

and i try to substarct greyscale image with same dimensions and i got an error too. can someone explain to me why i got an error please.

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot apply arithmetic operations on matrices of unequal sizes. You have to make them of equal sizes either by resizing or cropping.

Comment: Thank you, i try to resize it and it`s work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ZdaR (in the comment), I try to resize my image. to resize an image,

first need to define resize  :

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
```

and

```
 Mat Image,Temp;
 resize(Image, Temp, cvSize(Image2.size().width, Image2.size().height));
 //have same size with image2.
```